# Extlinux.conf on separate partition?

Tags: boot, bootable, u-boot, boot-process

I'm trying to configure a system with separate boot partition, booted with U-boot and `extlinux` loader.

Could I locate `extlinux.conf` on separate partition, but kernel (`zImage`) and device tree on root partition?

If so, how should I say in `extlinux.conf`, where to look for kernel image?

Answer (score 0):

The way that things are implemented today extlinux.conf needs to be on the same partition as the kernel / devicetree / initrd.